# Send html email using flask in Python

Tags: python, email, flask, html

I want to send HTML webpage as a mail body using Python and Flask. I tried using MIME module, but somehow I am not being able to send mail. If anyone has any expertise on this, can you please help me.

It would be great if you could provide some code as well.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/

Answer (score 21):

[flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) is a good tool that I use to render the template to render HTML as the body of my mail.

```
from flask_mail import Message
from flask import render_template
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    
def send_mail_flask(to,subject,template,**kwargs):
    msg = Message(subject=subject,sender='email@ofTheSender.com', recipients=to)
    msg.body = render_template('template.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template('template.html', **kwargs)
    mail.send(msg)
```

The template is the HTML file you wish to include in your mail and you can also add a text version using `msg.body`!

You may need to add more environment variables according to the SMTP service you use.

Comment: Thumbs up for msg.html

Comment: problem is flask-mail is dead :-(

Answer (score 5):

I recently made a [pretty awesome email library](https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail) and I decided to make a Flask extension for it as well: [Flask-Redmail](https://flask-redmail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

### Install

```
pip install flask-redmail
```

### Configuration

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_redmail import RedMail

app = Flask(__name__)
email = RedMail(app)

# Setting configs
app.config["EMAIL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["EMAIL_PORT"] = 0

app.config["EMAIL_USERNAME"] = "me@example.com"
app.config["EMAIL_PASSWORD"] = "<PASSWORD>"

app.config["EMAIL_SENDER"] = "no-reply@example.com"
```

### Simple Example

You may send emails simply:

```
@app.route("/send-email")
def send_email():
    email.send(
        subject="Example email",
        receivers=["you@example.com"],
        html="""
            <h1>Hi,</h1>
            <p>this is an example.</p>
        """
    )
```

### Template Example

It can also use your default Jinja env. Create a file *emails/verify.html* to your Flask template folder that looks like this:

```
<h1>Hi, you visited {{ request.endpoint }}.</h1>
```

Then use this template:

```
@app.route("/send-email-template")
def send_email():
    email.send(
        subject="Template example",
        receivers=["you@example.com"],
        html_template="emails/verify.html"
    )
```

Flask Redmail is quite a simple wrapper for Red Mail and Red Mail is pretty extensive. It can:

- Send attachments from various types
- Embed images and plots to the HTML
- Embed prettified tables to the HTML
- Supports Jinja out-of-the-box
- Gmail and Outlook are preconfigured

I hope you find it useful.

### Links:

- [Documentation](https://flask-redmail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/Miksus/flask-redmail)
- [Releases](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Redmail/)

### Red Mail:

- [Documentation](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail)
- [Releases](https://pypi.org/project/redmail/)

Comment: As Flask-mail has not been maintained since 2014 this seems like a great option. Was looking at this and Flask-Mailing as an alternative and ended up on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using FlaskMail https://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/

```
msg = Message(
    recipients=[''],
    sender='xx@zz.yy',
    reply_to='aa@bb.cc',
    subject=mail.subject
  )
msg.html = mail.body
mail.send(msg)
```

here, `mail` is an imported file from "mails" directory,
and `body` is an HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

On a separate python file (emails.py) I created an email class that contains all the emails (as class methods) to be sent to the user based on his actions as below:

```
class Email:

    def accountCreation():
        body = "<html> <body> <p> {} </p> <br> <br>  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p> </body> </html>"
        return body
```

then on another file (app.py) where I made use of flask_mail library I have:

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import emails

mailer = emails.Email()

try:
    email = "johndoe@mail.com"
    body = mailer.accountCreation()
    msg = Message('Hello',recipients=[email])
                                
    msg.html =  body 
    mail.send(msg)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure there's a folder in your apps directory called **templates**. This is where all your html templates should be.

```
**server.py**


from flask-mail import Mail, Message
from flask import Flask

import os

app = Flask(__name__)
send_mail = Mail(app)

 context={
   "fullname": fullname,
   "otp_code": otp_code,
   "year": datetime.now().year,
   "subject":"Registration Mail",
}
email_message = Message(
   subject=mail_subject,
   sender=os.getenv("ADMIN_EMAIL"),
   recipients=[receipients_email],
   html=render_template(template_name_or_list="otp.html", **context)
)
send_mail.send(email_message)
```

where "otp.html" is an existing html template in your templates folder